# Setting HTTP response headers (content-type) from JSP

Tags: jsp, http-headers

This should be the easiest thing in the world, but I haven't tried to do it in like forever. I need to (well, I *want* to) set the Content-Type of the HTTP response from JSP. I've googled around but finding valuable JSP information from the staggering mass of useless nonsense out there is a pain.

I know that I can get to the response through the response object in the page context, and from a zillion other places, but is there some "standard" JSP non-scriptlet way to set headers?

For now I'll probably just write an EL function as a hack but I'd prefer to do it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<%@page contentType="text/html" %>`

Comment: Oh durr.  Thanks; I knew it was something obvious.